# Input/output error

Tags: networking, bash, ssh

I am running the ubuntu desktop server on my old computer and after a few months of not using it, I plugged it back in and started getting errors like this for a good number of the commands I use regularly.

1. When I type "ping 8.8.8.8" I get (-bash: /bin/ping: Input/output error)
2. When I type "ssh -CX username@ip address" I get (-bash: /usr/bin/ssh: Input/output error)

Comment: Machines are generally used as desktops, or as servers. You've provided no release details and made it unclear.  I'd assume you have drive issues though (I/O errors on your local file system).  I'd SysRq reboot and boot 'live' media & explore your drive health (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools) . Note I don't know what system you're using, nor what data you have - thus I may perform some tasks before reboot first (ie. I'd reboot first if desktop, think about it if a server considering what machine is running & likely explore logs before reboot & do checks)

Answer (score 0):

Your disk / file system may have issues. Check your kernel log (`journalctl -kn 100`) if possible. If you are unable to run the command, use a live system and `journalctl -D xxx -n 1000` to see if you can get the log.